# how to run an asp.net app without a debugger attached

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I want to build my solution, and then open a browser and test it, without pressing F5. Should be simple, I am sure I have done this before many times but in other VS versions.

I just cant figure it out :) 
I have tried different settings on IIS and in the project settings for my app.
From VS, I use IISExpress and the project url is

```
http://localhost:1234/
```

I use asp.net mvc 5 with VS2013

I want to be able to close the VS instance and still run the app

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl+F5`? :)

Comment: What do you want to press then? Ctrl+F5?

Comment: If you don't want to debug, what do you want to do then?

Comment: Sometimes you just need to run the site locally without having to hit the debugger every time. I do this quite frequently. Being able to do it through VS allows you to eliminate the hassle of setting everything else up. 8^D

Comment: I want to be able to close the VS instance and still run the app

Comment: Install your app in IIS.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thats exactly what I am asking. how?

Comment: You can also right click your web project and click "View in Browser".

Comment: See http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configure-an-asp-net-website-on-iis.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For MVC applications. You typically need to do two steps.

1. Open the Project Properties. Select "Web". Select the "Specific Page" setting and leave it blank. Make sure no other settings have values either. This will force IIS Express to launch the app, but then the routing in MVC will take over.
2. Press CTRL+F5 to "Launch without Debugging". This launches the app without the debugger attached.

From there you can rebuild your application, but not have to press CTRL+F5 every time. IIS will detect the changes and refresh the ASP.Net worker process as needed.